# How can I always use the latest version of custom gradle wrapper

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I have a custom gradle wrapper which is used company wide. This wrapper is published to an Artifactory. Now it has version 1.0. The distributionUrl in the gradle-wrapper.properties is pointing to the artifactory and to the version 1.0.

When I now create a version 1.1 of that custom wrapper is there a possibility that the project which use that wrapper automatically pull the newest version or do I need to change the distributionUrl in each project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of, but this seems like a bad idea: one of the great things in the Gradle wrapper is that it allows you to be sure that your project uses the Gradle version it has been developed for and 'just works'. Having a moving version would defeat that.

For the sake of argument, I suppose you could do this by having a fixed url as the distributionUrl, and change the Gradle distribution on your web server, keeping the same fixed name (not sure how the Gradle wrapper would behave, and again this is a bad idea).

Instead, you could have a seed project (in Git) where you update the url, and propagate the changes in each project by merging the seed. This is easily automated, and as a bonus you can track when Gradle version changed for each project (and potentially broke the build) because you have the corresponding commits.

Comment: Hm.. good point. You're probably right. I'll stay with that manual update process with a Wrapper task.